# Unable to hook into SBApplicationIcon for tweak on iPhone 5, IOS 7.0.4

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, jailbreak

I am doing Jailbreak tweak dev for the first time and experimenting with some very simple test tweaks (based on a few tutorials) on an iPhone 5 with IOS 7.0.4 installed. My tweaks compile, link, package and I am able to install on my iPhone. However I cannot get a very basic tweak that links hooks into the SBApplicationIcon working. On the other hand another tweak that hooks into SpringBoard at launch to do the same thing (generate alert) DOES work. So whats going on?? Why is one tweak working and not the other. Have the SBApplicationIcon headers changed in IOS7?? I have a dump of headers from rpetrich's repository
For the tweak that does not work, I have tried adding syslog messages in the code to see if the code is even executed (have syslog enabled on the iphone), but nothing comes up.

**Tweak that does NOT work:**

```
   #import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    %hook SBApplicationIcon
    -(void)launch
    {
    NSString *appName = [self displayName];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The app %@ has been launched", appName, nil];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:appName message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        %orig;
    }
    %end
```

**Tweak that *does* WORK:**

```
#import <SpringBoard/SpringBoard.h>

%hook SpringBoard

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)application {
    %orig;

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome"
        message:@"Welcome to your iPhone Brandon!"
        delegate:nil
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

%end
```

Comment: What are you want to achieve? `SBApplicationIcon` is not the best place to detect app launch. Problem with your tweak may be very simple - `launch` method is not being called by iOS. You hooked it but it's just not being called by iOS. You need to find different method. `SBApplication -(void)activate` is a good place to detect app launch.

Comment: You may be right as some other open source tweaks I have downloaded from Cydia that hook into SB*Icon also dont work. Possible that these classes/launch methods are now deprecated in IOS7.

Answer (score 1):

`-(void)launch` has changed to `-(void)launchFromLocation:(int)location` in iOS7.